# Solr not able to get max(id)

Tags: apache, solr

I am new to Apache Solr and I am using 7.5 I have created a collection **TestCollection** with 2 fields **id** and **name**, id's default datatype is taken as string and the name's datatype is string.

I have indexed records by using curl and I have indexed id up to 400000 but when I give

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/TestCollection/select?json.facet={maxid:max(id)}&q=*:*&rows=0
```

I get as maxid as **99999**

```
facets: {
count: 495798,
maxid: "99999"
}
```

What is the mistake that I am making is it with the data type.

Comment: try the link...https://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent...you may need to change the type of id field...currently you have it as string...you may need to change it to integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abhijit mentions in the comment, change your field type.

A string field that starts with "9" will always be larger than (sort after) one that starts  with 4. This is the same as `Z` being sorted after `A`, as it's considered "larger". When using strings their sort order is based on each character by itself and not the "whole string".

Change the field type to a plong field and reindex your content, and both sorting and max would work as you expact it to do.